# Is one-past-end pointer OK for non-array object types?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer, pointer-arithmetic

Is this valid C++?

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int* pi = &i;
    ++pi;
}
```

I know that one-past-end pointers are allowed for array types, but I'm not sure in this case. Does that code technically have undefined behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is okay. It is one of the four categories of values any pointer type may hold.

> **[basic.compound]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3) Every value of pointer type is one of the following:
>
> - a pointer to an object or function (the pointer is said to point to the object or function), or
> - a pointer past the end of an object ([expr.add]), or
> - the null pointer value ([conv.ptr]) for that type, or
> - an invalid pointer value.
>
> A value of a pointer type that is a pointer to or past the end of an
>   object represents the address of the first byte in memory
>   ([intro.memory]) occupied by the object or the first byte in memory
>   after the end of the storage occupied by the object, respectively. [
>   Note: A pointer past the end of an object ([expr.add]) is not
>   considered to point to an unrelated object of the object's type that
>   might be located at that address. A pointer value becomes invalid when
>   the storage it denotes reaches the end of its storage duration; see
>   [basic.stc]. — end note ] **For purposes of pointer arithmetic**
>   ([expr.add]) **and comparison** ([expr.rel], [expr.eq]), a pointer past
>   the end of the last element of an array x of n elements is considered
>   to be equivalent to a pointer to a hypothetical array element n of x
>   and **an object of type T that is not an array element is considered to
>   belong to an array with one element of type T.**

As you can see, array types are also mentioned here, with their hypothetical object past the end. And as the [footnote in [expr.add]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#footnote-77) explains, the arithmetic to obtain a one-past-the-end pointer is *meant* to be valid too:

> As specified in [basic.compound], an object that is not an array element is considered to belong to a single-element array for this purpose and a pointer past the last element of an array of n elements is considered to be equivalent to a pointer to a hypothetical array element n for this purpose.

Comment: But that's _not_ what expr.add says (http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4). Editorial problem?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica - The footnote, while not normative, implies it's okay http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#footnote-77 - I think you are right on the editorial problem

Comment: Since "an invalid pointer value" is also a category here, would `pi += 2` also be OK? If not, why?

Comment: @Ayxan - A pointer value becomes invalid when the object that occupied the storage reaches the end of its lifetime. It's not a wildcard category to allow for random arithmetic. [expr.add] still stops you there.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Ah, yep. Nice

Comment: It would be great if you could explain them with some more example. The language is hard to explain!

Comment: @abhiarora - Explain what exactly? You are gonna have to be more specific.

Comment: Like what they mean by "invalid"? The pointer should have some address after the increment. And I am not able to grasp this statement "A pointer past the end of an object ([expr.add]) is not considered to point to an unrelated object of the object's type that might be located at that address. A pointer value becomes invalid when the storage it denotes reaches the end of its storage duration; see [basic.stc]. — end note"

Comment: @abhiarora If i am not wrong. "A pointer value becomes invalid when the storage it denotes reaches the end of its storage duration". here language is talking about a situation like a dangling pointer

Comment: @abhiarora - Like I told Ayxan, an invalid pointer value can come up when an object reaches the end of its lifetime. It was valid, then became invalid. As for the note, it means you are limited in the legal ways you may obtain pointers. Simply put `int a; int b; *(&a + 1) = 3;` - even if `&a + 1` points at `b`, that is still not a valid way to obtain a pointer to `b`.

Comment: Right. Now got it. Thanks!

Comment: So, If is valid and won't have any undefined behaviour unless we dereference it?

Comment: @abhiarora - What, the one-past-the-end? You can only use it in limited ways, those being arithmetic and comparisons. Everything else is UB.

Comment: I was asking about one-past-the-end! What about n-past-the-end? We can use in arithmetic and comparsion and as you said "Everything else is UB". I got confused as I saw someone saying the same thing and his answer was downvoted and removed by him later!

Comment: @abhiarora - There is no "n-past-the-end". You can't do the arithmetic that will get you there.

Comment: I can do `ptr += n;`?

Comment: @abhiarora - Unless the result is defined by `[expr.add]`, you can't.

Comment: Can you point me where it says it won't be valid? And why it is not?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica _A pointer value becomes invalid when the object that occupied the storage reaches the end of its lifetime_ This is wrong.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica _the object that occupied the storage_ are there (alive) objects that do not occupy storage?

Comment: _even if `&a + 1` points at `b`_ It is not possible to use pointer arithmetic to get from a pointer that [point](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#def:point) to one complete object a pointer that [point](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#def:point) to different complete object.

Comment: @abhiarora He removed it because it was wrong. Some people think that any pointer is fine as long as you do not dereference it. They are wrong.

Comment: When I write a book it's going to be very clear on what C++ isn't! This is not well enough understood for my liking

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica: The purpose of the C++ Standard is to specify requirements for a compiler to be considered "conforming".  It makes no effort to specify everything necessary to make a compiler suitable for any particular purpose.  There are some programs which the Standard does not require conforming implementations to process in any meaningful way, but that in no way implies that failure to meaningfully process some such programs wouldn't render an implementation unsuitable for some purposes, nor that such programs aren't written in C++.

Comment: @supercat We all know this. I'm not quite sure what you're getting at though? Why are you telling me this?

Comment: I was bristling at your line about "What C++ isn't".