# Iterating over a sequence of primitive type declarations using pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays

I was wondering if it would be possible to treat a sequence of primitive declarations as an array that could be iterated over using pointers. For background see this recent question:
[Is one-past-end pointer OK for non-array object types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59117564/is-one-past-end-pointer-ok-for-non-array-object-types#59117591)
So, consider the following code which attempts to iterate over a sequence of declarations using pointers (essentially tries to make an iterator system):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;
    int k = 2;
    int l = 3;

    int* begin = &i;
    int* end = &l;

    std::cout << begin  << " = " << *begin << " @ &i = " << &i << "\n";
    std::cout << end    << " = " << *end   << " @ &l = " << &l << "\n";

    if (begin > end) {
        while (begin != end - 1) {          //one past last int
            std::cout << *begin << " ";
            begin--;
        }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << &i << "\n" << &j << "\n" << &k << "\n" << &l << "\n";   //now comment out this line
}
```

This works with my compiler & system (`gcc-9.2 -Wall -pedantic` on WSL2.0 for Windows). The addresses for each int are assigned in descending order and so the result is:

```
0x7ffd48c8ee8c = 0 @ &i = 0x7ffd48c8ee8c
0x7ffd48c8ee80 = 3 @ &l = 0x7ffd48c8ee80   //12 spaces
0 1 2 3                   
0x7ffd48c8ee8c
0x7ffd48c8ee88
0x7ffd48c8ee84                                                                      
0x7ffd48c8ee80
```

What is odd is what happens when you comment out the last line of code, i.e you don't explicitly make references to each int i, j, k l:

```
0x7ffda6fcdf74 = 0 @ &i = 0x7ffda6fcdf74
0x7ffda6fcdf70 = 3 @ &l = 0x7ffda6fcdf70     // 4 spaces
0 3
```

It's as if the int variables are not really being assigned addresses until there's an explicit reference made.  Also, it doesn't matter where in the code the reference is used/made as long as it's after the declaration of the int variables. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: This is undefined behavior.

Comment: Undefined behavior is going on^^. The compiler does not see that `j` and `k` are being used and optimizes them out. He is allowed to do that, since what you are doing is undefined behavior. So he does not have to assume that they are needed and can remove them by the "as-if-rule". Try again with the compiler flag `-O0`.

Comment: The compiler is allowed to optimize out anything as long as it does not have any observable effects.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks I guess that explains it. I was thinking it was something like that because it doesn't matter where you put the all the & references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is undefined behavior. You cannot assume that the individual variable's addresses have any relation to one another except that the addresses of two different variables compare unequal in their lifetime.

Comparing pointers to two different complete objects (such as the local variables here) with `>` has unspecified results. Decrementing the pointer `begin` has in itself undefined behavior and so does `end - 1`.

The compiler is allowed to assume that your program does not exhibit undefined behavior and optimize based on that. It can reorder the variables as it sees fit and in particular it does not need to make sure that all variables have addresses if you don't explicitly take each variable's address. It can optimize away the variables completely if it can replace all places where they are read by the value they have at that point, if you don't take pointers explicitly.

Note that incrementing `begin` once would be allowed (one-past-the-object pointer). But any comparison with `end` would still give unspecified results and dereferencing it would still be undefined behavior. Incrementing `begin` twice would also be undefined behavior in any case. Decrementing is however not the same as incrementing, there is no one-before-the-object pointer and so decrementing `begin` or `end` even once has undefined behavior.